# Copying projection of existing defined raster file to define projection of feature class in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, modelbuilder

For arcmap, can i copy the projection of an existing defined raster file to define a projection of feature class?

I'm planning on doing this inside ModelBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you would use the [Create Spatial Reference](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-spatial-reference.htm) tool which:

> Creates a spatial reference for use in ModelBuilder.

...

> In ModelBuilder, the output of this tool can be used as input to tools
>   with a spatial reference parameter (for example, Create Feature Class,
>   Create Feature Dataset, and Make XY Event Layer).

...

> spatial_reference_template (Optional) [is] The feature class or layer
>   to be used as a template to set the value for the spatial reference.
>   [and can be a] Feature Layer; Raster Catalog Layer; Raster Dataset